# Fitting multiple von Bertalanffy growth curves to one plot by a factor

Tags: r, graph, plot

I have length at age data for fish. I have placed them into 3 groups dependent upon the bathymetry of the area, as Arbitrary Zone:

```
data.frame':    231 obs. of  7 variables:
$ Arbitrary.Zone: Factor w/ 3 levels "Offshelf","Shelf",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ Station       : Factor w/ 27 levels "DAL12_01","DAL12_02",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
$ Sample        : int  159 163 172 177 178 180 204 208 209 311 ...
$ Sex           : int  2 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
$ Unverified.Age: int  1 2 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
$ FL_mm         : num  66.1 67 88.8 42.6 48.7 ...
$ FL_mm_4rt     : num  2.85 2.86 3.07 2.55 2.64 ...
```

(Apologies if the code didn't show up properly. First time trying this.)

I have plotted length-at-age data and coloured it based on the Arbitrary Zone it is from:

```
plot(AgeLengthARCD$Unverified.Age, AgeLengthARCD$FL_mm,
col=AgeLengthARCD$Arbitrary.Zone)
```

(Apparently I am not allowed to post the plot)

Now I want to insert the 3 fitted curves onto the plot of Length vs Age, one curve for each zone. Herein lies the problem; is there a way to fit multiple curves (specifically von Bertalanffy growth curves) to one plot when the data is separated based on a factor (Arbitrary Zone)? For example, see http://fishbull.noaa.gov/984/22.pdf, Figure 1.

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks in advance,

Brittany

Comment: You can use `curve` to insert the growth curves. I'm a little confused as to what your problem is. Are you not sure how to split the data by zone? For this there is a function called `split`.

Comment: if you know how to fit a growth curve for a single group, you can (1) use `split` as @CCurtis suggests to split the data frame and fit the curves for each group using `lapply` or a `for` loop; (2) use functions from `plyr` to do the same thing in a slicker way; (3) use `gnls` from the `nlme` package, paying careful attention to the `param` argument.

Comment: My problem is what equation to use for the growth curves. Would it be the general equation `curve(FL_mm ~ Linf*(1-exp(-k(t-t0))))` and then make a `list()` with the values for the parameters Linf, k, and t0 for each zone? Because this is the code I was using to fit each curve separately: `mdl <- FL_mm ~ Linf * (1-exp(-K*(Unverified.Age - t0)))
on.shelf <- list(Linf=240.592145, K=0.20152637, t0=-0.75)
fitvonbOn.Shelf <- nls(mdl, data=AgeLengthShelf, start = on.shelf)
curve(fitvonbOn.Shelf)
fitPlot(fitvonbOn.Shelf, xlab="Unverified Age", ylab="Fork Length (mm)", main="von Bertalanffy On Shelf")`